# Leonardo (32u4): Timer0 problems with CTC mode

Tags: arduino-leonardo, timers

I want to use timer 0 to generate a rectangular signal on OC0A (D11) without the use of Arduino specific functions (that use timers for themselves). When I toggle D11 manually using a loop, I hear a sound in the connected piezo, but with my sample code, I don't hear something:

```
#define ALARM_PIN 11

void setup() {
  digitalWrite(ALARM_PIN, LOW);
  pinMode(ALARM_PIN, OUTPUT);
  noInterrupts();

  OCR0A = 60;
  // Toggle OC0A on compare match
  TCCR0A = (0 << COM0A1)
         | (1 << COM0A0)
  // CTC mode
         | (1 << WGM01)
         | (0 << WGM00);
  // prescaler = 256
  TCCR0B = (0 << WGM02)
         | (1 << CS02);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Any idea, what could be wrong?

**Update**

I've played with it a little bit more:

```
#define LED_PIN 9

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  TCCR0B = (1 << CS02);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, TCNT0 > 250);
}
```

This causes my LED to light very dim, so the timer is running up to 255. But as soon as I set TCCR0A, nothing is lighting up:

```
#define LED_PIN 9

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  OCR0A = 60;
  TCCR0A = (1 << WGM01);
  TCCR0B = (1 << CS02);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, TCNT0 > 0);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you connect an led to pin 11? What happens if you flip the polarity of the led around? (So pin11--resistor--led--ground and pin11--resistor--led--vcc). If pwm is working then the led should be lid either way.

Answer (score 2):

You should re-enable interrupts after you finish setting up. Use either

```
interrupts();
```

or

```
sei();
```

If you want to don't want to use the arduino specific commands. Even if the code does not need interrupts, background code does use them.

Timer 0 is used in arduino for some basic "house keeping" function like keeping time. I'm not sure if that could be part of your problem. you could try using a different timer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't need the interrupt, the port pin should be toggled automatically on compare match.

Comment: You are correct. I thought at the time that the bits would also control the compare match output, in any case you might not want to leave interrupts off.

Comment: Enabling interrupts at the end of `setup()` using `sei();` does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your value of `60` for `OCRA` will give you tone of around 16666hz which isn't audible to us humans. Try setting it to 255. That should give you a 4000hz tone, which is audible. (Or get your neighbors dog, and see if he dislikes hearing it)

You can use [this online calculator](http://eleccelerator.com/avr-timer-calculator/) to help you get the correct value for `OCRA`.

Note that you need 2 cycles to get a full wavelength (1 low and one high), so two toggles.

Comment: 16MHz + 256 prescaler and the OCRA set to 60 should give me ~500Hz. I've tried different values, even your 255 but without success.

Comment: A decent-sized portion of the population can hear 17kHz sounds. 19kHz would be a bit of a stretch though.

Comment: My mistake. I don't know where I got that 8-prescaler from.